# Issue with select statements in MySQL past exam paper

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Im going over a past paper and have found some select statements I cannot do. Can anyone help with these? I'm using MySQL. Thanks

Schema:

```
employee = (employee id, name, address, date of birth, salary)
project = (project id, name, budget, start date, end date)
manages = (employee id, project id)
works on = (employee id, project id)
```

Questions :

1. Names and addresses of all employees who work on projects which are
   current (have not ended yet)
2. The names of managers of projects, ordered by the total number of employees they manage
3. The names of employees who work on the project with the largest budget
   amount.

My attempts:

```
1. 
select employee.name, address
from employee natural join works_on natural join project
where end_date is null

2. 
select employee.name, count(works_on.employee_id) as manages_count
from (employee natural join manages) joins works_on using (employee_id)


I'm completely lost I cannot even attempt this one ^


3. 
select employee.name, address, budget
from employee natural join works_on natural join project
order by budget
limit n

^ I know this is wrong as technically I should be able to show them without a limit
```

Comment: updated - don't know if right though

Comment: Is it specified somewhere that ongoing projects have a null end date?

Comment: No - I just presumed this is how to answer it

Comment: Which one is your DBMS?

Comment: Don't use natural join. Also you are looking for aggregate functions and `GROUP BY`...

Comment: Well I would surmise that a project is current if its start date was before today, and its end date was either after today or, as you suggest, unspecified. But your NATURAL JOIN joins the tables on all commonly named columns - which, obviously, is not what you want. In general, we never use NATURAL JOIN, preferring instead to be explicit about how tables relate. Also, it seems the project table would want to be a part of that first query, given that it stores the project dates. It might be an idea to avail yourself of a beginners book or tutorial on sql, as this seems to be quite basic stuff.

Comment: Avoid natural joins like the plague. They work on paper but are not suitable for real world apps.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

1.

```
select
  e.name, 
  e.address
from employee e
join works_on w on w.employee_id = r.employee_id
join project p on p.project_id = e.project_id
where p.end_date is null
```

2.

```
select 
  n.name
from employee n
join manages m on m.employee_id = n.employee_id
join works_on w on e.project_id = m.project_id
group by n.employee_id
order by count(*) desc
```

3.

```
select 
  e.name
from employee e
join works_on w on w.employee_id = e.employee_id
join project p on p.project_id = w.employee_id
where p.project_id in (
  select project_id from project where budget = (
    select max(budget) from project
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much - this has helped lots!